# GridView pager page buttons accessibility

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pager

Can the page numbers (clickable) at the bottom of a gridview pager be accessed programmatically as buttons?

asp.net 3.0 c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.
I needed to add a onclientclick event to page buttons and have achieved this by doing something like:

```
myGridView.Attributes.Add("onClick", "setOKToClose();");
```

inside page_load

Comment: ?? I don't see how you've changed the page numbers to an actual button